Lifting a discrete group action to the total space of a circle bundle
Let $G$ be a discrete group acting on a smooth manifold $M$ via diffeomorphisms. Let $\pi:P\to M$ be a principal $S^1$-bundle over $B$ of first Chern class $c_1(P)$.
Is it true that, if for every $g\in G$ the map $f_g:M\to M$ is such that $f_g^\ast c_1(P)=c_1(P)$ then the group $G$ acts on $P$ via equivariant diffeomorphisms?
Can we say that $G$ acts on $P$ via ANTI-equivariant diffeomorphisms if $f_g^\ast c_1(P)=-c_1(P)$?
We recall that $f:P\to P$ is equivariant if $f(e^{it}\cdot p)=e^{it}\cdot f(p)$ and anti-equivariant if $f(e^{it}\cdot p)=e^{-it}f(p)$.
